# Parallelism in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, parallel-processing

how can i run one query in pl-sql- in parallel?

i need all the flow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create JOBs in order to run the same query with parallelism.

## EXAMPLE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE target_deletion
IS
   number_of_the_job   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   DBMS_JOB.submit (number_of_the_job, 'begin stored_procedure_for_deletion; end;', SYSDATE);
END;
/
```

## EXPLAINATION

Please suppose you have, in your Oracle DataBase, a stored procedure called exactly as follows:

stored_procedure_for_deletion

If you wish to execute that stored procedure many times with PARALLELISM, you have to create a stored procedure called for example "TARGET_DELETION" (written above), which creates a new job that invokes, with the PL/SQL block:

begin stored_procedure_for_deletion; end;

... the execution of your procedure called "stored_procedure_for_deletion".

The job starts immediately, so you can run the stored procedure target_deletion many consecutive times, in order to run the same procedure with parallelism.

Comment: thanks, but i need full example
because i dont know how to use parallelisem.

Comment: Parallelism is authomatic, I have shown an example on how to use it: you are obliged to create JOBs in order to use parallelism.

Comment: i have edited the definition of the variable:
number_of_the_job NUMBER;  Previously, I've written erroneously number_of_thejob NUMBER

Answer (score 3):

If enabled at instance level, Oracle itself has parallel query features:

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Parallel_Query_FAQ

edit: it's not clear what you are trying to do. Maybe you want ***asynchronous*** query execution, so the Oracle job suggestion is correct (see the other answer).

Oracle parallel feature is not asynchronous, it just says the optimizer to use a certain number of CPUs in query execution, to speed up the result. For example:

```
select /*+ PARALLEL(DOGS,4) */ * from DOGS where A>20
```

executes your query with parallelism at degree 4.

Comment: for example : my table name is DOGS , A,B,C -are column
i want to make simple query like : 
select * from dogs where A>20;

WHAT I NEED TO DO FOR RUN THIS QUERY IN PARALLEL- PLEASE GIVE ME THE SPECIFIED COMMANDS.
THANKS

Comment: See answer above - you add the PARALLEL hint. Look at the explain plan for the statement to see if it's used. Oracle's Tahiti site is a good starting point too.